# Converting an invariant matrix to a non-invariant tensor

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus, invariants

I'm working on the following problem:

> In 4-dimensional notations, given a transformation matrix
>
> [image: transformation matrix]
>
> Calculate the matrices $\Lambda_{\mu\nu}$, $\Lambda_\mu^\nu$ and $\Lambda^{\mu\nu}$

The matrix $\Lambda_\mu^\nu$ seems simple enough, as it should simply be the transpose of $\Lambda_\nu^\mu$, which in this case is identical s.t. $\Lambda_\mu^\nu = \Lambda_\nu^\mu$.

As I understand it however, $\Lambda_\mu^\nu$ and its transpose are invariant matrices, but $\Lambda_{\mu\nu}$ and its transpose are only tensors (not invariant, not matrices).

I've looked for other examples of such a transformation, but so far I only get tensors with both lower or upper indices that are used as a notation for matrix dot products.

Is this a trick question? Or is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a relativity problem with a non-Euclidean metric tensor.  If I am correct you need to raise and lower indices by applying the metric tensor.  If you are dealing with a flat space-time you have either diag(-1, 1, 1, 1) or diag(1, -1, -1, -1) depending on signature.

Lambda_mu_nu = g_mu_alpha*Lambda^alpha_nu, summed over alpha.

Pardon my archaic notation ^ is an upper index, _ a lower index.

For example the (0,0) entry of the new tensor would be:

Lambda_0_0 = g_0_0 * Lambda^0_0 + g_0_1 * Lambda^1_0 + g_0_2 * Lambda^2_0 + g_3_0 * Lambda^3_0

Comment: You are right, sorry. I'm doing a course that is dealing with both electrodynamics and minkowski space - I put the wrong tag.

Comment: I didn't even see the tag.  Does my answer help?

Comment: I'm trying to work it out explicitly now. This notation is new to me so I'm a bit slow with it. 

$\Lambda_{\mu\nu} = g_{\mu\alpha}*\Lambda^\alpha_\nu = \begin{bmatrix}g_{00}\Lambda^0_0 & g_{01}\Lambda^1_0 & g_{02}\Lambda^2_0 & g_{30}\Lambda^0_3\\g_{10}\Lambda^0_1 & g_{11}\Lambda^1_1 & g_{12}\Lambda^2_1 & g_{31}\Lambda^1_3\\g_{20}\Lambda^0_2 & g_{21}\Lambda^1_2 & g_{22}\Lambda^2_2 & g_{32}\Lambda^2_3\\g_{30}\Lambda^0_3 & g_{31}\Lambda^1_3 & g_{32}\Lambda^2_3 & g_{33}\Lambda^3_3\end{bmatrix}$ right?

Comment: We are using diag[1,-1,-1,-1] in class. So my result would then be a matrix $\begin{bmatrix}cosh(\theta) & 0 & 0 & -sinh(\theta)\\0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\sinh(\theta) & 0 & 0 & -cosh(\theta)\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: that last column in my first comment has wrong indices, let's pretend they are the other way around :P

Comment: No that is not correct, you need to sum over the dummy index alpha.  Just like in matrix multiplication each entry will be a sum of 4 terms.

Comment: I have added an example of the (0,0) calculation in the answer.

Comment: thanks! So (with some omissions b/c character limit) its a normal matrix operation:

$\Lambda_{\mu\nu} = g_{\mu\alpha}*\Lambda^\alpha_\nu = \begin{bmatrix}g_{00}\Lambda^0_0+g_{01}\Lambda^1_0+g_{02}\Lambda^2_0+g_{03}\Lambda^3_0
 & 0
 & 0
 & g_{30}\Lambda^0_3+g_{31}\Lambda^1_3+g_{32}\Lambda^2_3+g_{33}\Lambda^3_3\\g_{10}\Lambda^0_1+g_{11}\Lambda^1_1+g_{12}\Lambda^2_1+g_{13}\Lambda^3_1 & -1 & 0 & 0\\g_{20}\Lambda^0_2+g_{21}\Lambda^1_2+g_{22}\Lambda^2_2+g_{23}\Lambda^3_2 & 0 & -1 & 0\\g_{30}\Lambda^0_3+g_{31}\Lambda^1_3+g_{32}\Lambda^2_3+g_{33}\Lambda^3_3 & 0 & 0 & -cosh(\theta)\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: but it still spits out this matrix?

$\begin{bmatrix}cosh(\theta) & 0 & 0 & -sinh(\theta)\\0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\sinh(\theta) & 0 & 0 & -cosh(\theta)\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Is that not the correct answer?  Make sure you are using the correct signature.  And realize that you are "representing" the tensor as a matrix because it has 2 indices.  Also, you have some entries in the wrong place in your comment.  Not sure that had an effect.

Comment: I see it. I've been at it for 4 hours and im buzzing. cant edit the old one anymore:

$\Lambda_{\mu\nu} = g_{\mu\alpha}*\Lambda^\alpha_\nu = \begin{bmatrix}g_{00}\Lambda^0_0+g_{01}\Lambda^1_0+g_{02}\Lambda^2_0+g_{03}\Lambda^3_0  & 0  & 0  & g_{00}\Lambda^0_3+g_{01}\Lambda^1_3+g_{02}\Lambda^2_3+g_{03}\Lambda^3_3\\g_{10}\Lambda^0_0+g_{11}\Lambda^1_0+g_{12}\Lambda^2_0+g_{13}\Lambda^3_0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\g_{20}\Lambda^0_0+g_{21}\Lambda^1_0+g_{22}\Lambda^2_0+g_{23}\Lambda^3_0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\g_{30}\Lambda^0_0+g_{31}\Lambda^1_0+g_{32}\Lambda^2_0+g_{33}\Lambda^3_0 & 0 & 0 & -cosh(\theta)\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: That looks closer to being correct.  Again, are you expecting an answer you cannot get?  If so, let's move to chat and I can continue to help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87193/discussion-between-enzolima-and-ggcg).